# Does anybody know how to access a remote sqlite database using objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, sqlite, odbc

I'm developing a simple macosx application and it needs to access a remote sqlite database (must be sqlite).
I've been looking for an example on how to do it through ODBC (I don't know if ODBC is the best or easy way).
Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't. SQLite is local only.

Comment: SQLite is open source. You could – in some way – change the source code so that you can create a database handle to a virtual file which points to a remote file. I don't know how to do this, but what migoux asks **must** be possible in some way...

Comment: On the sqlite website they said that it's possible: "Using SQLite on a Network

SQLite database files may be shared accross a network using a network filesystem. This is never a particularly efficient method and may have problems (depending on the filesystem, or may simply not be available."
And then they list some alternative techniques. http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it in another way (like Koing Baard said).
I mounted the remote sqlite folder (through mount_afp) and it worked.

Thanks all!